# Custom built review plugin - pagination not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently create a plugin that takes all comments from all products and places them under the review tab for all comments.

Inside Wordpress I have the following setting checked:
Settings > Discussion > Break comments into pages with...

This enables pagination on the default comment section. I've added this code with my code but it doesn't enable pagination, even when I remove the If statement.

```
          <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
          echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
          paginate_comments_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args', array(
              'prev_text' => '&larr;',
              'next_text' => '&rarr;',
              'type'      => 'list',
          ) ) );
          echo '</nav>';
      endif; ?>
```

I'm currently using this function to call all reviews into one:

```
function products_all_reviews(){
$args = array ('post_type' => 'product');
  $comments = get_comments( $args );
  wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ), $comments );
}
```

What needs to be done to call/enable pagination properly? This is my first time creating plugin so the help is much appreciated